# How can I trigger a process after a returned publisher would be subscribed?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a function that returns a publisher. This publisher gives the results of a background process. I only want to trigger the background process when the publisher would be subscribed, so that no results are lost. The background process can update its results many times, so the variant with `Future` is not suitable.

```
private let passthroughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Data, Error>()

// This function will be used outside.
func fetchResults() -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
     return passthroughSubject
     .eraseToAnyPublisher()
     .somehowTriggerTheBackgroundProcess()
}

extension MyModule: MyDelegate {
     func didUpdateResult(newResult: Data) {
          self.passthroughSubject.send(newResult)
     }
}
```

What have I tried?

Future:

```
Future<Data, Error> { [weak self] promise in
     self?.passthroughSubject
          .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
               // My logic
          }, receiveValue: { value in
               // My logic    
          })
          .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)
      self?.triggerBackgroundProcess()
}.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Works the way I want but the subscriber is called only once (logical).

Deffered:

```
Deferred<AnyPublisher<Data, Error>>(createPublisher: { [weak self] in
   defer {
      self?.triggerBackgroundProcess()
   }
   return passthroughSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Debugger shows that everything is correct: first `return` then `trigger` but the subscriber is not called for the first time.

`receiveSubscription`:

```
passthroughSubject
.handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] subscription in 
   self?.triggerBackgroundProcess()
})
.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The same effect as with `Deffered`.

Is it even possible what I want to achieve? 
Or, it is better to create a public publisher subscribe it and receive results from background process. And the `fetchResults()` function doesn't return anything?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why your last code is not the solution. You detect the subscription, you kick off the background process, the background process does `.send` to the Subject whenever it feels like it, done.

Comment: @matt But in fact it doesn't work. The subscriber is not called for the FIRST result of the background process. I suspect that triggering is faster than subscribing to the publisher.

Comment: Well you could introduce a delay so that the triggering is later, couldn't you?

Comment: The last code should work. It also comes in at the proper thread, for example if you call ```.subscribe(on: someProcessingQueue)``` upstream, however it refuses to send items unless you explicitly wrap your background work inside a ```DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own type that conforms to `Publisher` and wraps a `PassthroughSubject`. In your implementation, you can start the background process when you get a subscription.

```
public struct MyPublisher: Publisher {
    public typealias Output = Data
    public typealias Failure = Error

    public func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream)
        where Downstream.Input == Output, Downstream.Failure == Failure
    {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        subject.subscribe(subscriber)

        startBackgroundProcess(subject: subject)
    }

    private func startBackgroundProcess(subject: PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            print("background process running")
            subject.send(Data())
            subject.send(completion: .finished)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this publisher starts a new background process for each subscriber. That is a common implementation. For example [`URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift) issues a new request for each subscriber. If you want multiple subscribers to share the output of a single request, you can use the `.multicast` operator, add multiple subscribers, and then `.connect()` the multicast publisher to start the background process once:

```
let pub = MyPublisher().multicast { PassthroughSubject() }
pub.sink(...).store(in: &tickets) // first subscriber
pub.sink(...).store(in: &tickets) // second subscriber
pub.connect().store(in: &tickets) // start the background process
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your last bit of code is a perfectly viable solution: don't trigger the background process until you detect the subscription. Example:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
func start() {
    self.subject
        .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: {_ in
            print("subscribed")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.doSomethingAsynchronous()
            }
        })
        .sink { print("got", $0) }
        .store(in: &storage)
}
func doSomethingAsynchronous() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.subject.send("bingo")
        }
    }
}
```